# Migrate from .netframework 4.6 to .Net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-framework-version

Actually i am migrate  from .NetFramework4.6 to .Netcore 3.1 but i am facing this error
[image]

my csproj file

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="xunit" Version="2.3.0-beta2-build3683" />
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-xunit" Version="2.3.0-beta2-build3683" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <Folder Include="Properties\" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

APp.confg file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

[image]

Comment: Post your `*.sln` file.

Comment: their is no file with this extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your app compiles as class library. You need to change the output type to console app:

Add `OutputType` to your `.csproj` file like below:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

You can also change this in Project Properties -> Application -> Output Type in Visual Studio.

Comment: we do not require to change APP.config while converting .netframework to .net core???

Comment: Please check this one . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61873561/migrate-azure-cloud-serviceworker-role-net-framework-4-6-2-to-net-core-3-1